# How to get terrorism dataset?

Tags: dataset

I am doing my project in data mining stream. Like, finding terrorism activity in social media. For that, we need terrorist data set. But we could not get it, because it is confidential. Can anyone suggest us a way to find the data set?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the appropriate site to ask for a resource like this. I vote to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for it here http://mlearn.ics.uci.edu/MLRepository.html

Also you can look for a paper about the topic and ask the authors for the dataset

Also you can do your own dataset using apis like twitter api to look through twiter and serch for keywords like terrorism

I hope this helps